# Nodeclipse, as referencing linked resources in javascript files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodeclipse

I have a node application in nodeclipse and I have a "module not found" error when run this line of code:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
```

This is because the `index.js` file is in a virtual folder in my nodeclipse project. How can reference linked resources in javascript code? I created a path variable in the properties of the project but it doesn't work with `${variable_name}` construct.

Answer (score 0):

When launching Node from within Eclipse (or any IDE) the usual `node` executable is running, and it is not aware of any Eclipse virtual folders and links.

Probable Linux/Windows OS file system links should work (not IDE's)
and you can check by running `node` from command line or within Eclipse TCF Terminal (included with latest Enide Studio <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)